# Correct expression for in-plane right Cauchy-Green tensor for surface embedded in 3D

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics

I have a surface embedded in a 3D Cartesian frame undergoing a deformation and want to know the correct expression for right Cauchy Green tensor **in the tangent plane of the surface**.

A point $\mathbf{X}$ ($\mathbf{x}$) in the initial (deformed) configuration is given by a mapping of curvilinear coordinates in a parametric plane:

$\mathbf{X}=\phi_X(\xi^1, \xi^2),  \quad (\xi^1, \xi^2) \in  \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$\mathbf{x}=\phi_x(\xi^1, \xi^2),  \quad (\xi^1, \xi^2) \in  \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$.

For the initial surface, a covariant tangent basis is defined as $\mathbf{G}_\alpha = \frac{\partial X^m}{\partial \xi^\alpha} \mathbf{e_m}$. Therefore the transformation from the parametric to the initial configuration can be described by the deformation gradient
$\mathbf{F}_0 = \frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial\mathbf{\xi}}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ and the covariant components of the metric tensor $\mathbf{G}=\mathbf{F}_0^T \mathbf{F}_0\in\mathbb{S}^{2}$  of the initial surface is can be obtained as $G_{\alpha\beta} = G_\alpha \cdot G_\beta $.

Similarly, for the deformed surface we have $\mathbf{g}_\alpha = \frac{\partial x^m}{\partial \xi^\alpha} \mathbf{e_m}$, $\mathbf{F}_n = \frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{\xi}}\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times2}$ , and $\mathbf{g}=\mathbf{F}_n^T \mathbf{F}_n\in\mathbb{S}^{2}$ where $g_{\alpha\beta} = g_\alpha \cdot g_\beta $.

The contravariant components of the bases ($\mathbf{G}^{\alpha}$ and $\mathbf{g}^{\alpha}$) and metrics ($G^{\alpha\beta}  $ and $g^{\alpha\beta}$) are obtained per standard procedures.

The actual **material** deformation from the initial to deformed surface is given by the deformation gradient $\mathbf{F}=\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}=\mathbf{g}_\alpha \otimes \mathbf{G}^\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$. The right Cauchy Green tensor is thus $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{F}\in\mathbb{S}^{3}$. Now note that $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are rank 2 ie have a null space along the normal of the surface, which is spanned by vectors $\mathbf{v}$ for which $\mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{v} =\mathbf{0}$.
Therefore the *in-plane deformation* (the deformation in the tangent plane) can be described by a tensor $\mathbf{\bar{C}}$ whose components form a 2x2 matrix. Is the following correct: $\mathbf{\bar{C}}=\mathbf{G}^{-1}\mathbf{g}$? If not, what is the correct expression?